# Fades out upon close, jQuery

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I have a problem on this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nm_close').click(function(){
        $('.map_pops').css('display','none');
    });
});
```

What I want is this bubble popup will fades out when it closes. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `fadeOut(250);`?

so, `$('.map_pops').fadeOut(250);`

btw:  250 is the milliseconds it should take to fade out.  So 5000 would be 5 seconds(ish).

Comment: Does the fadeOut automatically set the value to 'display:none' ?

Comment: it will hide the element yes.

Comment: Oh, and if there are elements under it, all the elements move up as expected.

Comment: You are welcome.  Don't forget to mark this as the correct answer for others that might be having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the fadeOut() function (see: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nm_close').click(function(){
        $('.map_pops').fadeOut(<duration>);
    });
});
```

is the length of time you want it to fade out over be it slow, fast etc. Its all in the documentation of fadeOut()